# PHP Variable Array for Function Names

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables, foreach

I'm trying to implement some hooks into a WordPress theme, but rather than write out every function with repetitive code I was wondering if I could use an array to declare the functions instead.

E.g. ordinarily i'd use something like:

```
function hook_name_1() {
    do_action( 'hook_name_1' );
}

function hook_name_2() {
    do_action( 'hook_name_2' );
}
```

Is there a way to place the hook/function names into an array and then call them with one foreach loop or something similar? Something like the following:

```
$hook_array = array(
home_name_1,
hook_name_2
);

foreach ($hook_array as $hook) {
    function $hook() {
        do_action( $GLOBALS['hook'] );
}
}
```

The do_action do_action part within the function works fine like this, but it's the variable function names that I can't figure out.

Is it possible to set an array like this and then create the function names from the array values?

Comment: Can't you just call `do_action()` instead of creating the wrapper function? If you really must do this to create *named* functions rather than anonymous functions you can [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) it, but that is a distinct code-smell.

Comment: You *could* define a bunch of functions with [`create_function()`](http://www.php.net/create_function), but that solution is just as bad as `eval()`.

Comment: Have you asked yourself if this is really necessary? Defining functions dynamically may seem practical, but it is really crummy.